# Include WP_Query in my own PHP file?

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-query, code, include

I want to write a cronjob for myself. But I need to get access to `WP_Query` and the permissions to delete posts etc.

My question now is, how can I include the `WP_Query` function to my own PHP file and do I need to edit or change some permissions in order to delete or create posts with that cronjob?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Load WordPress in custom PHP Script:

You need to load essential WordPress core functionality in your custom PHP script for `WP_Query` to work properly.

For example, let's say you have a custom PHP file named `my-cron.php` and WordPress is installed in the web root, like this:

```
public_html/
    index.php
    my-cron.php <--
    wp-load.php
    wp-settings.php
    ...
    wp-admin/
    wp-content/
    wp-includes/
```

In this setup, if you want to use `WP_Query` in `my-cron.php` file, you need to load the `wp-load.php` file. So in `my-cron.php` file you need to have the following CODE:

```
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}
```

## Access WP_Query:

At this point, you'll have the access to `WP_Query`, so you can use it like this:

```
// simply selecting posts with category name "wordpress"
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'wordpress' ) );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
else {
    echo "No post found for category named wordpress";
}
```

## Delete Posts:

However, WP_Query doesn't have delete function. For that you'll either need to use the [`wp_delete_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/) function or [`WPDB`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) class. Using `wp_delete_post()` is recommended as it'll take care of many dependencies, however, if you need more control, then you may use `WPDB` class or `$wpdb` global variable, but be careful if you choose that path.

For example, the following CODE will delete the post with ID `1`:

```
$deleted = wp_delete_post( 1 );
if( $deleted === false ) {
    echo "Couldn't delete Post with ID=1";
}
else {
    echo "Deleted Post with ID=1";  
}
```

Of course you can combine `WP_Query` with `wp_delete_post` to find and delete posts that meet specific criteria.

## Setup Cron:

Once you are done writing the custom PHP script, you need to [setup cron job](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-into-the-system-task-scheduler/#mac-os-x-and-linux) to run as a HTTP request, like the following:

```
5 * * * * wget -q -O - http://your-domain.com/my-cron.php
```

## Security:

Since accessing `WP_Query` or `wp_delete_post` function **doesn't require any authentication** (or permission) by default, you need to make sure `my-cron.php` is not publicly  accessible. For example, you can add the following at the beginning of `my-cron.php` file to give access to `localhost` only:

```
$allowed_ip = '127.0.0.1';
if( $allowed_ip !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) {
    exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to iterate through all my posts from page `product`? - Because my problem is, I get this error message: `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388616 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1842`

Comment: There are many other ways, you can even run custom query. But first you need to find out what exactly the problem is, a normal query shouldn't exhaust memory unless you have a lot of posts. I suggest you post another question with the CODE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this to delete or create sites within a WordPress Multisite environment?
If so, you can access WP_Query to handle sites by putting the function into a PHP file in a network-activated mu-plugin's folder.

Comment: Nope, it's a normal site

Comment: So you're wanting to create a cronjob to delete a single site?

Comment: Yes - that must be automated. But I need WP_Query for this

Comment: If you're dealing with a single site, you can't create a WordPress query that creates or deletes an entire single site, as it has to install/uninstall WordPress entirely. If you were working in a multisite environment, there are functions to create and delete sites built into the system that can be called.

Comment: Sorry... I mean a cronjob who is deleting pages and not the hole site!

Comment: You can use [wp_delete_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) and [this awesome post from Tom McFarlin](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/) to achieve what you need, I think.