# How to use woo commerce login to authenticate code php pages?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login

I have a doubt as follows,

I have a store in wordpress using woo commerce. I have some other services in that same site and I want to code that pages in core php. So, now the question is, is there any option to use woo commerce login authentication to use in my core php pages?

Please give me your suggestions. Waiting for your valuable reply.

Explaination:
1. Online medine store is in woo commerce.
2. I want to have 1 more service called doctor appointment booking using core php.

I need a common user login to the registering user to view their orders and appointments.

Comment: you don't have to do that just to let people view their appointments.
You can create product/service that would require the users to pay for the appointments and based on the payment you can send them mail to confirm their appointment

Comment: why don't you make a plugin to handle doctor appointment booking, in this way not  only you can use core php but you can use all functionality of wordpress and woocommerce. and if you just want to add view for orders and appointments you can add a page to my-account section ( of course for this one you need to be familiar with woocommerce templates and hooks)

Comment: Thanks Maverick & Arash Rabiee: As I am not much familiar with Woo commerce & Word press I can't write plugins. I normal core php we will create a session and check in all the pages to authenticate the user right? I can write a code like that. Now the problem is I need to use Woo commerce login user to continue with my core php pages also. I need the session value which is created while woo commerce login. Then I can check the Session in my core php pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the WP environment in order to verify the user's login. Have a look at these previous answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304926/how-to-include-wordpress-functions-in-custom-php-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251705/load-wordpress-page-content-from-external-php

[Include WP_Query in my own PHP file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258694/include-wp-query-in-my-own-php-file)

You might also find it helpful to add `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` to stop WP from loading the theme, etc, if it's not needed in your php script.